# Parse a json object with multiple sub-objects inside with GSON

Tags: json, gson, retrofit

i have an issue with the response of an API that i want to use, i was developing an APP that consumes this API using **Retrofit 1.9.0** and **GSON 2.3.1**.

The Json that i want to  parse is like:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "address": "bar"
  },

  "user2":{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "foo",
    "addres":"bar"
  },

  ... it can be any number of users ...

  "userN":{
    "id": N,
    "name": "foo,
    "address": "bar"
  }

}
```

So i have an POJO named `User`:

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I was trying to parse that json with the configuration `Map<String, User>`:

```
Callback< <Map<String, User> > callback
```

But when i run it, i have a GSON error:

```
gson expecting array but found object
```

How can i parse the json in a correct way?

PD: i can't change the API response, it's an external API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying a concrete type for you callback, like `HashMap`.  `Map` is an interface.

```
Callback< <HashMap<String, User> > callback;
```

Usually you will get casting exception instead of a parsing error, but worth a try.